# Nginx reverse proxy server

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have 2 Ubuntu servers running on same location in digital ocean and the first one running as webserver(nginx) and the other one running as app-server(Nodejs)

Webserver sending request through private ip and as you guys can guess the app-server is not allow the direct requests.

My question is I have image/upload directory in the app-server such as : /srv/upload/user_images and I want to get those images from a web browser.

For example : www.myappserveripaddress.com/srv/upload/user_images/image1.jpeg

but the privilages would be the only image can be accessed from outside.None can access the /srv/upload/user_images/ to see the all images.

I dont know if its possible or not. Only if the user knows the image name , he can enter the ip.com/srv/upload/user_images/imageName.jpg . If this is possible what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand your question but in order to link the user to a certain set of images you could append to the name of the image the UserID.

If you have a database, each time a user uploads an image you can also save there just the name of the picture he saved, then when the image is saved in the filesystem you save it with the name {UserID}-{imageName}.jpg.

On his pictures menu he can easily see a list maybe of all the picture names he uploaded. These names are taken from the database and are not a link to a file on the server.  Only when he clicks the image a request is constructed for a resource called /server/images/{UserID}-{imageName}.jpg.

The UserID here ensures you do not have duplicate image names in your server.

Hope this helps. If it is in any way wrong please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You must write an api and client between your servers. Logic is that: end user wants to access an image. Nginx (probably php) receives the request and creates a new request to nodejs. It checks the image path and returns the image to nginx, nginx returns image data to client.